# Is it possible to read files from multiple input fields?

Tags: javascript

So for example, If I have a form that contains multiple input fields with type set to 'file', is it possible to read the file you uploaded from a certain input field with same class.

for example:

```
<input type = "file" class = "fileSelector"/>
<input type = "file" class = "fileSelector"/>
<input type = "file" class = "fileSelector"/>
```

JS part

```
for(var i = 0; i < fileSelector.class; i++){
   fileSelector[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
      console.log(fileSelector[i].file)
    })
}
```

Comment: can you make it more clear?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense currently. Please edit it.

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it be. If you have the file's contents you can do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change','.fileSelector',function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('files'));
)
```

this would work.